# Push Notification issue in android marshmallow and lollipop

Tags: android, push-notification

I tried push notification its working fine in android JellyBean but same code not working marshmallow and lollipop.

Device getting other app notification like whatsapp,gmail.. cant say problem with settings also.

googled it some icon changes new versions but am not getting notification also, thanks guys :)

My Notification Code:

```
 NotificationIntent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
        NotificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        NotificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, NotificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("GREEK NEWS")
                .setContentText(content)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(NotificationPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager = (android.app.NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            NotificationManager.notify(86, NotificationBuilder.build());
        } else {
            NotificationManager.notify(86, NotificationBuilder.getNotification());
        }
```

Comment: Which device ? Is there any app installed on that device like autostart manager that stop background jobs.

Comment: Am Testing in Moto G3

Comment: is Notfication coming for popular app like whatsapp?

Comment: Then there is some app or check settings for battery performance section in your device that black list your app.

Comment: checked and modified battery setting also

Comment: Did you figure out what was causing this? We have a lot of Android 6 users who, after updating our app, no longer get push notifications. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try change icon of nofitication

```
.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
```

and create method

```
private int getNotificationIcon() {
    boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
    return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.notification_icon : R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
}
```

Hope. It help you !!!

Answer (score 0):

try to use following method. I checked for version if lollipop or > then lollipop,i used vector based icon and also used NotificationCompat.Builder to generate notification.Tested in all versions.Hope this will help you.

```
 public void simpleNotification(Context context,String message)
    {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        //intent.putExtra("isFromBadge", false);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.app_icon);


        boolean whiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setLights(Color.RED, 100, 1900)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);


        mBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(whiteIcon ? R.drawable.ic_notification : R.drawable.app_icon);

        if(whiteIcon)
           mBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorPrimary));

            //mBuilder.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));



        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);

        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        // hide the notification after its selected
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
```

Comment: Tried am not getting push notificaton @Harshal Bhatt